# NuxtJS - How to add vConsole.js to Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, debugging, console, nuxt.js

How do I add vConsole.js to Nuxt?

```
// debugging
import VConsole from "vconsole";
const vConsole = new VConsole();
```

This causes the error `window is not defined`

I am stuck... any help very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window` isn’t defined on the server-side. You need to use vConsole as a client side plugin.

```
plugins/vConsole.client.js

import VConsole from 'vconsole' 
Vue.use(VConsole)
```

Don’t forget to add it to your `nuxt.config.js`

```
plugins: { src: '~/plugins/vConsole.client.js' }
```

Comment: thank you!!!!!
`
import Vue from 'vue';
import vConsole from 'vconsole';
const vc = new vConsole();
Vue.use(vc);
`

Answer (score 0):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import vConsole from 'vconsole';

const vconsole = new vConsole();
Vue.use(vconsole);
```

this did the trick.